# Problem with the height of my last section

Tags: html, css

I am starting as a developper front-end and learning to code in HTML and CSS.
I am struggling with the last section of my code, there is a big empty space, I am trying to find a solution but never could, if someone can help me, that would be perfect !
Also I would like to know what I did wrong, it'll help me to learn even more :)

Here the empty spot

[image: img]

Thanks in advance !!

```css
.activites {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.colonnesimple {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.colonnedouble {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.colonnesimple img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 16px 16px 0 0;
}

.colonnedouble img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 16px 16px 0 0;
}

.activites .colonnesimple figure {
  width: calc(100% / 1.2);
  height: 59%;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #55555538;
  border-radius: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.activites .colonnedouble figure {
  width: calc(100% / 1.2);
  height: 28%;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #55555538;
  border-radius: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.activites .colonnesimple figure figcaption {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.activites .colonnedouble figure figcaption {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section id="activitesmarseille">
  <div class="contenuactivites">
    <h5>Activités à Marseille</h5>
    <div class="activites">
      <div class="colonnesimple">
        <figure>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="imagesolo" src="images/activites/3_medium/reno-laithienne-QUgJhdY5Fyk-unsplash.jpg" alt="Image du Vieux Port">
            <figcaption>
              <h6>Vieux Port</h6>
            </figcaption>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="colonnedouble">
        <figure>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="imagedoublegrd" src="images/activites/3_medium/paul-hermann-QFTrLdQIRhI-unsplash.jpg" alt="Image du Fort de Pomègues">
            <figcaption>
              <h6>Fort de Pomègues</h6>
            </figcaption>
          </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="imagedoublept" src="images/activites/3_medium/kevin-hikari-rV_Qd1l-VXg-unsplash.jpg" alt="Image des îles du Frioul">
            <figcaption>
              <h6>îles du Frioul</h6>
            </figcaption>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="colonnesimple">
        <figure>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="imagesolo" src="images/activites/3_medium/kilyan-sockalingum-NR8-cBCN3aI-unsplash.jpg" alt="Image du Parc National des Calanques">
            <figcaption>
              <h6>Parc National des Calanques</h6>
            </figcaption>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="colonnedouble">
        <figure>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="imagedoublept" src="images/activites/3_medium/florian-wehde-xW9e8gdotxI-unsplash.jpg" alt="Image de Notre-Dame-de-la-Garde">
            <figcaption>
              <h6>Notre-Dame-de-la-Garde</h6>
            </figcaption>
          </a>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="imagedoublegrd" src="images/activites/3_medium/lena-paulin-wH2-EJoDcV0-unsplash.jpg" alt="Image du Parc LongChamp">
            <figcaption>
              <h6>Parc LongChamp</h6>
            </figcaption>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing your height properties ?

Answer (score 0):

So problem was with **height: 59%;** which u provide at **%**, because that u have empty space on the end of the page, solution:

```css
.activites {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.colonnesimple {
  width: 25%;
}

.colonnedouble {
  width: 25%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.colonnesimple img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 16px 16px 0 0;
}

.colonnedouble img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 16px 16px 0 0;
}

.activites .colonnesimple figure {
  width: calc(100% / 1.2);
  height: 257px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #55555538;
  border-radius: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.activites .colonnedouble figure {
  width: calc(100% / 1.2);
  height: 120px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #55555538;
  border-radius: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.activites .colonnesimple figure figcaption {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.activites .colonnedouble figure figcaption {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section id="activitesmarseille">
  <div class="contenuactivites">
    <h5>Activités à Marseille</h5>
    <div class="activites">
      <div class="colonnesimple">
        <figure><a href="#">
            <img class="imagesolo" src="https://www.imgacademy.com/sites/default/files/2009-stadium-about.jpg" alt="Image du Vieux Port">
            <figcaption>
              <h6>Vieux Port</h6>
            </figcaption>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="colonnedouble">
        <figure><a href="#">
            <img class="imagedoublegrd" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSe6kwbxkuKpLxeNP_O6LGoJxIkuhatjNvZ0gPcRr4DpziONgkIsqNOl09dfZduQJHH_6k&usqp=CAU" alt="Image du Fort de Pomègues">
            <figcaption>
              <h6>Fort de Pomègues</h6>
            </figcaption>
          </a>
        </figure>
        <figure><a href="#">
            <img class="imagedoublept" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTRnsZZ1ZwCEhb4spOX3eIMeN3KbwZaAJo6mypioWrvsaNPfb5TFNu8kjrtEvrADqvoRdA&usqp=CAU" alt="Image des îles du Frioul">
            <figcaption>
              <h6>îles du Frioul</h6>
            </figcaption>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="colonnesimple">
        <figure><a href="#">
            <img class="imagesolo" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT2qwQpNH5dPV0dLoPl7InPlMPUf0eWWMG4POrt56FeF62yCUZA-qVBMKb3UDi6I2lj30k&usqp=CAU" alt="Image du Parc National des Calanques">
            <figcaption>
              <h6>Parc National des Calanques</h6>
            </figcaption>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="colonnedouble">
        <figure><a href="#">
            <img class="imagedoublept" src="https://www.imgacademy.com/sites/default/files/styles/scale_2500w/public/2017-03/Campus%20Center.jpg?itok=Bs2r8s-1" alt="Image de Notre-Dame-de-la-Garde">
            <figcaption>
              <h6>Notre-Dame-de-la-Garde</h6>
            </figcaption>
          </a>
        </figure>
        <figure><a href="#">
            <img class="imagedoublegrd" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTGOfJEHAIvVjPI8TXLLrMgwXWZiPx0FkU3dBiBExfIDy-ISANxSh2ulIvA9f86y_yu-sU&usqp=CAU" alt="Image du Parc LongChamp">
            <figcaption>
              <h6>Parc LongChamp</h6>
            </figcaption>
          </a>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Ah yeah it worked with putting the height of the figure in pixels! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter more problems like this I advice to use the inspector (CTRL+SHIFT+C) of your browser
and simply hover over the problem to see where the problem may be. In this case probably a height value that is too high.

Comment: Yes, i am trying to use this more and more, it's really helpful ! Thanks !